# Let $X$ be an arbitrary set equipped with the trivial topology $\{\emptyset, X\}$. Show that $\pi_1(X) = \{1\}$.

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

I've just learned about homotopy and so many things are still confusing. I'd like to get some hints and explanation for this exercise. It is designed for me to get used to the basic concepts, so I'd like to keep the proof elementary.

Let $\alpha$ be a loop in $X$ with base point $p$, and $c_p$ be the constant loop at $p$. From the definitions, I assume that I will need to find a map $F: I \times I \to X$ such that $F(x,0) = \alpha(x)$ and $F(x,1) = c_p(x), \ \forall x \in I.$ Is this the right direction? How should I proceed after this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X$ is equipped with the trivial topology, then *any* map from any topological space into $X$ is continuous. So, define $F$ so that both conditions that you stated hold and that will be it.

Comment: So the point of having $X$ equipped with the trivial topology is to have $F$ continuous without any further condition?

Comment: Yes. Actually, I would put it in a slightly different way: the point of having $X$ equipped with the trivial topology is to have $F$ automatically continuous.

Answer (score 4):

Stronger condition holds. If $x_0\in X$ then $\{x_0\}$ is a (strong) deformation retract of $X$ via

$$F:X\times I\to X$$
$$F(x,t)=\begin{cases}
x &\text{if }t=0 \\
x_0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Thanks to the trivial topology $F$ is continuous.

In particular $X$ is contractible, hence $\pi_1(X)$ is trivial.